# How to efficiently import the same module into multiple sub-packages in python

Tags: python

I want to create a Python package that has multiple subpackages. Each of those subpackages contain files that import the same specific module that is quite large in size.

So as an example, file `A.py` from subpackage `A` will import a module that is supposedly named `LargeSizedModule` and file `B.py` from subpackage `B` will also import `LargeSizedModule`. Similarly with `C.py` from subpackage `C`.

Does anyone know how I can efficiently import the same exact module across multiple subpackages? I would like to reduce the 'loading' time that comes from those duplicate imports.

Comment: There is no loading time from duplicate imports; the import itself happens once, then it's just a lookup (in `sys.modules`, IIRC). What has made you think that this is a problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see. I just started building the barebones of my package and wanted to prevent something like this from making me overhaul the entire package structure if it becomes a possible efficiency issue later on. I am newb :) Thanks.

For other newbs this link might make good reading on the subject: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504313/python-what-is-the-cost-of-re-importing-modules

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By doing `import LargeSizedModule` everywhere you need it. Python will only load it once.

Comment: @TomW To add to this, the only time `Python` will re-import something is if you call `reload(LargeSizedModule)` on it or use your own `importlib.import_module()` and give it a different common name.